# JQuery .css() function with conditional logic

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, function

I'm practicing conditional logic within certain JQuery functions. `$('h2').css({backgroundColor: 'red'});` works, but when I add the conditional logic below it no longer works. If I change the return value to a string it will get rid of the error, but it still doesn't change the background color. What am I doing wrong?

```
$('h2').css({function(){
    if (1 === 1){
        return backgroundColor: 'red';
    }
    else {
        return backgroundColor: 'purple';
    }
}});
```

Comment: Generally, you cant return multiple things, and you can only return values (whole strings, numbers, objects...) . This might work but only if you format the return value to return something like "baclgroundColor : 'purple' " (note the quotes)

Comment: I didnt phrase this correclty when I said "multiple things", but there are good answers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your example code will cause a syntax error. You can use callback functions for [jQuery.css](https://api.jquery.com/css/) in one of two ways.

An object with properties and their callback functions.

```
$('h2').css({
    backgroundColor: function(){
        if (1 === 1){
            return 'red';
        }
        else {
            return 'purple';
        }
    }
});
```

Or with a single property and callback function pair.

```
$('h2').css('backgroundColor', function(){
    if (1 === 1){
        return 'red';
    }
    else {
        return 'purple';
    }
});
```

In this way, you can conditionally apply CSS per-element.

Answer (score 10):

Try this code:

```
$('h2').css({backgroundColor: (1 === 1) ? 'red' : 'purple'});
```

It's the shorthand of `if` condition.

In this case, the shorthand of `if` condition is more reliable and cleaner.

**By the way,** it's a plain old javascript.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm sure this will make it work, but it would be more useful to the OP to first explain what's wrong with his code.

Comment: I'm new to JQuery and had no idea you could write it this way. Very interesting. Thank you.

Comment: @Bryan Thanks. I just discovered this one with **jquery** and **angularjs** with my project. This is not necessarily for jquery usage only. It's a plain old javascript. I'm glad it helps.

Comment: There is no such thing as "jQuery usage only." jQuery is a JavaScript library; there's nothing you can do with it that you couldn't do with plain JavaScript.

Comment: @Juhana I'm referring about the shorthand of **if** condition not about the jquery codes.

Comment: I know what you're referring to. I'm just saying that it's moot; everything you do with jQuery is "plain JavaScript."

Comment: @Juhana I've mentioned plain **old** javascript. I mean without using a js framework.

Answer (score 5):

Fascinating thought experiment!  The issue is that you are passing a function reference to the `.css` function which accepts strings and objects only.  Try encapsulating the function so it returns the return result rather than the function reference:

```js
$('h2').css((function(){
  if (1 === 1){
    return {backgroundColor: 'red'};
  }
  else {
    return {backgroundColor: 'purple'};
  }
})());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Cool thought experiment</h2>
```

Answer (score -3):

Is more cleaner keep your style in the style sheet file and is more cleaner
to use the toggleClass handler

```
.highlight{//Put this in your style sheet file
    background-color : red;
}

'//===>This will add the to the element the highlight if it doesn't have it or else will returned back to the original style

$('h2').on('click',function(){
    $(this)toggleClass('highlight');
})
```